# When I open my terminal, I receive the following message -> /Users/pankajkumar/.zshrc:[:9: ']' expected

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

It seems that whenever I open my terminal in Mac M1, I get this error message. I have attached a screenshot of the terminal, as well as a .zshrc file. If anyone knows the solution, please let me know.

**The terminal displays this information**

/Users/pankajkumar/.zshrc:[:9: ']' expected
pankajkumar@Pankajs-MacBook-Pro ~ %

**Data inside .zshrc file**

local brew_opt_path="/opt/homebrew/opt"
local nvm_path="$HOME/.nvm"

export PATH="${brew_path}:${PATH}"
export NVM_DIR="${nvm_path}"

[ -s "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/nvm.sh" #This load nvm

[ -s "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"] && . "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" #This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: You have a syntax issue in your zshrc. If you post it as text it will be easier to fix (although I think this question is probably off-topic for this site anyway).

Comment: Easy: Trace the execution of your .zshrc, identify the syntactically incorrect line, fix it.

Comment: Hello, I just updated my question. Please take a look at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces matter when dealing with the brackets:

```
[ -s "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"] && . "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" #This loads nvm bash_completion
```

This must be like so:

```
[ -s "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" #This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Notice the space between **nvm"** and **]**.